# Couldn't find with 'id' (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have created db connection and define models in .rb file and trying to find records, query with `find` only is working fine but query with `find`, `conditions` not working.

my .rb file:

```
require 'mysql2'
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter=> 'mysql2',
:database=> 'qa_1705',
:username=> 'root',
:password=>''
)

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_schema_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :schema_attributes, :dependent => :destroy   
end

class SchemaAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :item_schema_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
end

class ItemSchemaAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :schema_attribute
  belongs_to :line_item  
end

#Works fine :
p Company.find(24)
#<Company id: 24, name: "ABC.pvt.ltd", address: "xyz">

#Not working, throws error:

p ItemSchemaAttribute.find(:first,:conditions => [ "schema_attribute_id = ?", 22])

Couldn't find all ItemSchemaAttributes with 'id': (first, {:conditions=>["schema_attribute_id = ?", 22]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2) (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

full error:

```
/home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:336:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!': Couldn't find all ItemSchemaAttributes with 'id': (first, {:conditions=>["schema_attribute_id = ?", 22]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2) (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    from /home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:479:in `find_some'
    from /home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:438:in `find_with_ids'
    from /home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
    from /home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
    from /home/ac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:128:in `find'
    from connect_db_active_record2.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

i have created rails app with same structure and it is working fine in rails console also i found that generated error converted `ItemSchemaAttributes` from `ItemSchemaAttribute`

Comment: why don't you use `where` instead of `conditions`?

Comment: Which version of the Rails you are using?

Comment: i am using Rails 2.3.18

Comment: But your activerecord is 4.2.1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh!

i got the answer, the problem is with `activerecord` gem installed in system vs gem installed in rails application.

i have activerecord version 2.3.18 in app. so it is working file in app console.

but when i run ruby program it points to system's `activerecord` which is 4.2.1 so `find(:first, ...)` and `find(:all, ...)` will not work.

Comment: that's why you need to use `bundler` gem to maintain the **gems along with version** synchronized across all platforms

Answer (score 3):

`find(:first, ...)` and `find(:all, ...)` has been deprecated since Rails 3.2.12 and likely removed with Rails 4.+

You should be using the right idioms:

`Model.where(conditions)` to get a collection

and

`Model.find_by(conditions)` or `Model.where(conditions).first` to get a single item.

`Model.find()` now only accepts a primary key value as a parameter.

And `ItemSchemaAttribute.find_by_schema_attribute_id(22)` no longer works for Rails 4.+

Comment: I try before answer to execute `find_by_schema_attribute_id`, it works just fine. I got activerecord 4.2.6.

Comment: My bad. I just stopped using dynamic finders since 3.2. But according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations: `All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated.` Still, I would encourage to use `Model.find_by()` instead of dynamic finders.

Comment: I agree with. I just place this code here for everyones interest. It is up to us to use one method or another)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is obsolete syntax for activerecord 4.2.1.
In ActiveRecord 3 you could try

```
 ItemSchemaAttribute.where(schema_attribute_id: 22).first
```

In ActiveRecord 4 you should do

```
ItemSchemaAttribute.find_by(schema_attribute_id: 22)
```

or

```
ItemSchemaAttribute.find_by_schema_attribute_id(22)
```

**UPDATE**
If you like to use old syntax (which I do not recommend) you can try [activerecord-deprecated_finders](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders) gem.
I don't use it for myself but it seems like this gem supports `find` with conditions hash

Comment: how should it work if this syntax is not supported by activerecord 4.2.1?